# Impossible geometry problem?

Tags: geometry

I created a simple graphic that is pretty similar to what my paper says. Here it is below:

[image]

Anyway, the last problems like this, the full length was given, for example; in the past problems, AD was also given to me as something like 14, or some other whole number and it asked for x and/or a line segment inside, however, this time AD was not given, so I have no idea how to even start solving this problem...any ideas? Thanks! (sorry if I am posting this in the wrong format or in the wrong sub-StackExchange site, I'm new to Mathematics.

Just saw this: EC bisects AD at C

Comment: I've taken the liberty of embedding the image myself.

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that $C$ is the midpoint of $AD$?

Comment: No, it mentions nothing about midpoints.

Comment: The short answer is that: without more info, you can't solve for $x$. You sure this wasn't a multi-parter with the value of $AD$ being "carried over" from an earlier part?

Comment: But it does say EC bisects AD at C, would that mean the midpoint?

Comment: @TrivisionZero Yes, that helps. See my answer.

Comment: @TrivisionZero. Please include the important fact about bisecting as part of your question to make out complete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $EC$ bisects $AD$, it means that the segments $AC$ and $CD$ are equal in length.

So $3x + 6 = 2x + 14 \implies x = 8$ and $AC = 3x + 6 = 30$

Comment: Thanks, we just learned the term bisect in class, and I guess I forgot.